# Save song to document directory from ios music library

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller, avassetexportsession

I am making a music app in which user can access ios music library and can save the songs to its app(that is documents directory). I am able to access music library with MPMediaPickerController but dont know how to handle  its delegate method so as  to save the selected song to my document directory. 
Currently i am using this code

```
- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker
   didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) collection
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self playSelectedMediaCollection: collection];
}


- (void) playSelectedMediaCollection: (MPMediaItemCollection *) collection {

    if (collection.count == 1) {
        NSArray *items = collection.items;
        MPMediaItem *mediaItem =  [items objectAtIndex:0];
        [self mediaItemToData:mediaItem];
    }
}



-(void)mediaItemToData:(MPMediaItem*)mediaItem
{
    // Implement in your project the media item picker

    MPMediaItem *curItem = mediaItem;//musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem;

    NSURL *url = [curItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

    AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL: url options:nil];

    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset: songAsset
                                                                      presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];

    exporter.outputFileType = @"public.mpeg-4";

    NSString *exportFile = [[self myDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                            @"exported.mp4"];

    NSURL *exportURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportFile] ;
    exporter.outputURL = exportURL;



    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [[self myDocumentsDirectory]
                                                    stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"exported.mp4"]];
//    
//    NSLog(@"%@",data);
//    NSURL *audioUrl = exportURL;
//    NSLog(@"Audio Url=%@",audioUrl);
//    audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:audioUrl];
//    NSLog(@"%@",audioData);
    // Do with data something
    // do the export
    // (completion handler block omitted)
    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
     ^{
//         int exportStatus=exporter.status;
         NSLog(@"%d export status",exporter.status);
         if (exporter.status==AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted)
         {
             NSLog(@"successfull");
         }
         NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [[self myDocumentsDirectory]
                                                         stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"exported.mp4"]];

         NSURL *audioUrl = exportURL;
         NSLog(@"Audio Url=%@",audioUrl);
        audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:audioUrl];
         NSLog(@"%@",audioData);
         // Do with data something

     }];
}
```

In the above code, the debugger never comes to the export session asynchronous block. Let me know if there are any modifications required in above code, or if you have any working code available for my requirement.
THANKS in advance....

Answer (score 2):

I think was missed

`/`

try this code

`NSString *exportFile = [[self myDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:                             @"/exported.mp4"];`

**UPDATED**

or cause can be presetName which you use

> /* This export option will cause the media of all tracks to be passed through to the output exactly as stored in the source asset, except for
>      tracks for which passthrough is not possible, usually because of constraints of the container format as indicated by the specified outputFileType.
>      This option is not included in the arrays returned by -allExportPresets and -exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset. */
>   AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough       NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);

here is good description about exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler: [https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AV‌​AssetExportSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Still not able to debug  block  [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:

I just want to know firstly, why my compiler dosent goes to this block and  why i am unable to get my export status

Comment: The block is being called but everytime my export status is 4 ie failed. I dont know what i am missing.

Comment: you ask about working code with export session… are you tried [this example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/avexporter/Introduction/Intro.html)?

Comment: does export session support mp3 files?

Comment: @RahulMathur yes it supporting go through this doc https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009539

Answer (score 1):

for Swift 3.0 or 4

```
func mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {
    mediaPicker.dismiss(animated: true) {

        print("You selected \(mediaItemCollection)")

        let item: MPMediaItem = mediaItemCollection.items[0]
        let pathURL: URL? = item.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? URL
        if pathURL == nil {
            print("Picking Error")
            return
        }

        // get file extension andmime type
        let str = pathURL!.absoluteString
        let str2 = str.replacingOccurrences( of : "ipod-library://item/item", with: "")
        let arr = str2.components(separatedBy: "?")
        var mimeType = arr[0]
        mimeType = mimeType.replacingOccurrences( of : ".", with: "")

        // Export the ipod library as .m4a file to local directory for remote upload
        let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: AVAsset(url: pathURL!), presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
        exportSession?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        exportSession?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A

        let documentURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        let outputURL = documentURL.appendingPathComponent("custom.m4a")

        //Delete Existing file
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputURL)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }

        exportSession?.outputURL = outputURL
        exportSession?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: { () -> Void in

            if exportSession!.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed  {
                print("Export Successfull")
            }

        })

    }

}
```

Comment: hi! Maybe you know how to export files to the format as they are in the Music Library? Without conversion to m4a or another.